# Values that don't correspond

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures

Hey I am trying to create a stored Procedure that will bring me back information of all Property's That have not been added to a group.

I have two tables:

GroupDetails

```
InspectionGroupID    PropertyID
9                    12
8                    13
6                    14
10                   25
```

PropertyMaster

```
PropertyID      ManagerID      AddressLine 1
12                  2          34 Easter Road   
13                  0          104 Montgomery Street    
14                  0          67 Holyrood Road 
15                  1          45 Lala
16                  0          34 Uptown
```

I have been thinking something like this but its not working. I also have a search filter on a treeview this is the reason for the @SearchValue.

```
Alter PROCEDURE [dbo].[GroupManagmentProperties_LoadRecords]
        @SearchValue varchar(30) = NULL

    AS
    BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON;
SELECT        PropertyMaster.PropertyID, PropertyMaster.AddressLine1, InspectionGroupDetails.PropertyID
FROM            PropertyMaster INNER JOIN
                         InspectionGroupDetails ON PropertyMaster.PropertyID = InspectionGroupDetails.PropertyID WHERE AddressLine1 LIKE '%' + @SearchValue + '%' and PropertyMaster.PropertyID <> InspectionGroupDetails.PropertyID  
ORDER BY AddressLine1

END
```

Answer (score 2):

If you're looking to return records that aren't referenced you need an outer join, left or right.  This will still produce records which you can then check for the found references and filter appropriately.

```
Alter PROCEDURE [dbo].[GroupManagmentProperties_LoadRecords]
(
    @SearchValue varchar(30) = NULL
)
AS
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON;

    SELECT
        PropertyMaster.PropertyID, PropertyMaster.AddressLine1, InspectionGroupDetails.PropertyID
    FROM PropertyMaster
    LEFT JOIN InspectionGroupDetails ON PropertyMaster.PropertyID = InspectionGroupDetails.PropertyID
    WHERE InspectionGroupDetails.PropertyID IS NULL
        AND AddressLine1 LIKE '%' + @SearchValue + '%'  
    ORDER BY AddressLine1;
END
```

Comment: I believe that the predicate "PropertyMaster.PropertyID <> InspectionGroupDetails.PropertyID" was the attempt to get left join results and should be omitted.

Comment: @erik-blessman Thanks! I thought I chopped the WHERE clause and didn't notice that was hanging around.

Comment: @jtimperley this code is not bringing back any results at all?

Comment: @RichardGlass Could you please remove your address filter and check the base query?